# How to do `defined` with a hash slice

Tags: perl

I'm trying to learn Perl better, and learn hash slices.

Instead of 3 different `if (defined` statements, I'm trying to tidy the code to make it more maintainable and readable, but have come across the following conundrum:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':all';
use Carp 'confess';
use DDP; # a.k.a. Data::Printer
use JSON 'decode_json';

my $hashref;
$hashref->{Jane} = decode_json('{"sex":"Female","Mortality_Status":"Alive", "latest_date":"2020-11-26","Hospitalized":"no","Risk_Status":"NA"}');
p $hashref; # pretty print the data
my @needed_terms = qw(age BMI sex);
if (defined @{ $hashref->{Jane} }{@needed_terms}) {
    say 'all terms are defined.'; # this is what it says, which is WRONG!!!
} else {
    say 'some terms are missing.'; # Jane is missing BMI and age, so the script should print here
}
```

I've read [How to do sum of hash reference slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65837342/how-to-do-sum-of-hash-reference-slice) and https://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference to no avail.

This person `Jane` is missing both `age` and `BMI` information, so the `if (defined` statement should say that some terms are missing, but is instead passing.

I get the same error whether I use `@{ $hashref->{Jane} }{@needed_terms}` or `%{ $hashref->{Jane} }{@needed_terms}`

I've also thought that maybe `defined` is returning how many terms of the slice are defined, but that isn't true.

How can I set `if (defined` statement on a hash slice properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good place to use `all` from [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#all):

```
use List::Util qw(all);

if (all { exists $hashref->{Jane}{$_} } @needed_terms) {
    say 'all terms are defined.';
} else {
    say 'some terms are missing.'; # Jane is missing BMI and age, so the script should print here
}
```

It loops through all the needed terms and checks to see if each [exists](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists) as key to the `Jane` hash.

---

One of my favorite docs for Perl Data Structures is [perldoc perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc).  It is more of a step-by-step tutorial than *References quick reference*.